# Avoid two php petitions happening at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing on a prestashop website that has two js scripts that are executed at the same time, when the document is ready. Both are ajax petitions. My problem is that the user I use to connect to the database has a maximun of one connection at the same time and,as both scripts are executed at the same time, it always throws an exception.

I was wondering if there is some way to make an script way until there are not petitions to the server. I mean, making the second script wait until the first one has finished it's job.

It would be great if I could do this without having to change the first one, as it's a default script of Prestashop.

Thank you beforehand :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function ajaxfunc() {
    var load = $.get('functions.php');
    $(".div").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log("Mlkia kaneis");
      $(".div").html('failed to load');
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".div").html(res);
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
    //CALL THE OTHER AJAX FUNCTION HERE <------
    });
```

You can use the `load.done`. Basically once this is done execute the other one